# Twitter4J Android Search Query Returns Null

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to develop an android application, and for my purpose, I've to be able to search tweets based on the Hashtag the user searches. I'm using Twitter4j Library and I have also Consumer API key/Secret and tokens.

What I've tried so far:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


        // Twitter 4j 25.May.2019 only for test right now
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("ABC")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("ABC")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("ABC")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("ABC");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build());
        final Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        Query query = new Query("twitter4j");
        try {
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
            }
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.out.println(te.getMessage());
        }
```

I expect some JSON request from Twitter, but on my console it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the code, or with Twitter4j library, the problem was with Network configuration, specifically with "NetworkOnMainThreadException".

To fix the issue see here: [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)